# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Service' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I just switched my computer and one of my project is no longer running properly and throws the error in title. *(you may also find complete error message below)*  It is clearly looking for wrong place but at this point I'm not sure what to change.  Please advise.

> **Some facts to keep in mind**
>
> - I did not change no line of code in source
> - It is working fine on new production server which gets deployed by *VSTS*
> - I'm using *IISExpress* to run it
> - I'm using *Visual Studio 2015 v14.0.25431.01 Update 3*
> - One of the main difference from my last computer, this one has *Visual Studio 2017 RC* in it. *(I don't think that's causing anything but who knows)*

### Programs and Features

Following application exist

- WCF Data Services 5.6.3 Tools

### *Bin* directory

Following files exist

- Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll
- Microsoft.Data.OData.dll
- Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll
- Microsoft.Data.Services.dll

### DataService.svc *(complete)*

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Factory="System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Service="Company.Project.Services.DataService" %>
```

### Web.Config *(partial)*

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.29.0" newVersion="4.2.29.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

### Error Page

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

*Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Source Error:**

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

**Assembly Load Trace:** The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Source/github/company/repository/project/HubServices/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Source\github\company\repository\project\HubServices\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Source\github\company\repository\project\HubServices\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\user\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 5.0.0.0 redirected to 5.7.0.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError) +34
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceParser.GetType(String typeName) +55
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceParser.GetCompiledType(Assembly compiledAssembly) +76
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceParser.CreateParseString(Assembly compiledAssembly) +38
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceBuildProvider.GetCustomString(CompilerResults results) +33
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +182
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults results) +16
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) +10098689
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +294
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +103
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) +82
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String virtualPath) +31
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.GetCompiledCustomString(String normalizedVirtualPath) +163
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +201
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +52
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +641

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/DataService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +481507
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +174
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +11
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  had to re-open that project, realized assembly is not in the loaded **Modules**.  I checked the output directory which was set for `bin\{Configuration}` changing it to `bin` solved the issue.